# SQL to retrieve column info including references

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I'm trying to query the database schema to retrieve information about the column configuration. Included in the result set I want a list of foreign keys which are referencing a column. Hopefully somebody here may spot an error in my query, which always returns an empty set.

```
SELECT

C.ORDINAL_POSITION          AS `position`,
C.COLUMN_DEFAULT            AS `default`,
C.IS_NULLABLE               AS `nullable`,
C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH  AS `max`,
C.NUMERIC_PRECISION         AS `size`,
C.NUMERIC_SCALE             AS `scale`,
C.COLUMN_TYPE               AS `type`,
U.TABLE_NAME                AS `referenced`,

CASE C.COLUMN_NAME WHEN NULL
  THEN U.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
  ELSE C.COLUMN_NAME
END AS `name`

 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
 RIGHT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS U
   ON U.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
   AND U.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
 WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
   AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database'
 ORDER BY `position` ASC
```

Comment: You should be using `LEFT JOIN`, not `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar Wouldn't a left join return only a single reference?

Comment: They both return all matches. The difference is what happens when there's no match -- LEFT JOIN returns all the rows from the first table, RIGHT JOIN returns all the rows from the second table.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe I've confused myself. I know there will be one entry on the left and zero or more on the right. I thought I'd need a right join returning the values from the right (with null left) but including the common table name :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT

    C.ORDINAL_POSITION          AS `position`,
    C.COLUMN_NAME               AS `name`
    C.COLUMN_DEFAULT            AS `default`,
    C.IS_NULLABLE               AS `nullable`,
    C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH  AS `max`,
    C.NUMERIC_PRECISION         AS `size`,
    C.NUMERIC_SCALE             AS `scale`,
    C.COLUMN_TYPE               AS `type`,
    U.TABLE_NAME                AS `referencing_table`,
    U.COLUMN_NAME               AS `referencing_column`

 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
 LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS U
   ON U.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
  AND U.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
 WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
   AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database'
 ORDER BY `position` ASC
```

A `LEFT JOIN` returns all the rows that an `INNER JOIN` would return. In addition, it returns any rows in the left table (`COLUMNS`) that have no match, with `NULL` values for the columns from the right table.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. All these joins are why I like working with ORMs.